# Content provider in Android by Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

everyone!

I created a side application for practice Kotlin in Android. I create a provider like that:

```
class TestProvider : ContentProvider() {
    companion object {
        val sUriMatcher = UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH)
        val MATCH_WITH_TEST = 0

        init {
            sUriMatcher.addURI("$APPLICATION_ID.provider", TestEntity.TABLE_NAME, MATCH_WITH_TEST)
        }
    }

    var mDatabaseHelper: LocalSQLiteHelper? = null

    override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
        mDatabaseHelper = LocalSQLiteHelper(context)
        return true
    }

    override fun insert(uri: Uri?, values: ContentValues?): Uri? {
        if (mDatabaseHelper != null && !mDatabaseHelper?.writableDatabase?.isReadOnly) {

        }

        return uri
    }
}
```

You see! The content provider has to contain a Database Helper. This Database Helper only created at `onCreate()` method of the parent class.

So now I want to check the `writableDatabase` be a read-only database or not. Because the `mDatabaseHelper` is `LocalSQLiteHelper?` so `!mDatabaseHelper?.writableDatabase?.isReadOnly` code return `Boolean?` which not accepted in Kotlin `if` control statement.

Have any one got the same problem with me?

Update:

I found a solution by using:

```
val database: SQLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper?.writableDatabase as SQLiteDatabase
```

It work but I dont know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `let`:

```kotlin
override fun insert(uri: Uri?, values: ContentValues?): Uri? {
    mDatabaseHelper?.let {
        if (it.writableDatabase.isReadOnly) {

        }
    }

    return uri
}
```

`?.let { it  ->  ... }`  gives you database helper object inside of a closure if it's not null.

Comment: Thank U for your help. Let me search document about `let` first.

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm you should also check out `run` and `apply`. :)